# How to remove duplicate elements of, list of dictionaries in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, duplicates, hashable

I have a list of campuses:

```
campus = [{'id': '1', 'dlin': '1'}, {'id': '2', 'dlin': '1'},{'id': '3', 'dlin': '1'},{'id': '4', 'dlin': '2'},{'id': '5', 'dlin': '2'},{'id': '6', 'dlin': '1'}, ]
```

each campus belongs to a school with a unique dlin. I want to have a list in which I have some other lists, each having a few dictionaries.
I run the below code:

```
schools = []
for i in campus:
    ls = []
    for j in campus:
        if i['dlin'] == j['dlin']:
            ls.append(j)
            # campus_copy.remove(j)
    schools.append(ls)
[print(item) for item in schools]
```

the result is:

```
[{'id': '1', 'dlin': '1'}, {'id': '2', 'dlin': '1'}, {'id': '3', 'dlin': '1'}, {'id': '6', 'dlin': '1'}]
[{'id': '1', 'dlin': '1'}, {'id': '2', 'dlin': '1'}, {'id': '3', 'dlin': '1'}, {'id': '6', 'dlin': '1'}]
[{'id': '1', 'dlin': '1'}, {'id': '2', 'dlin': '1'}, {'id': '3', 'dlin': '1'}, {'id': '6', 'dlin': '1'}]
[{'id': '4', 'dlin': '2'}, {'id': '5', 'dlin': '2'}]
[{'id': '4', 'dlin': '2'}, {'id': '5', 'dlin': '2'}]
[{'id': '1', 'dlin': '1'}, {'id': '2', 'dlin': '1'}, {'id': '3', 'dlin': '1'}, {'id': '6', 'dlin': '1'}]
```

I have to either remove the duplicate members from schools or modify the code such that I do not get duplicates.
When I try to remove duplicates from schools, I see that dic item is not hashable so I can not do it.
To solutions are available that are somewhat similar to my problem.
[Remove duplicates from list of dictionaries within list of dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38593527/remove-duplicates-from-list-of-dictionaries-within-list-of-dictionaries)
[Remove duplicate dict in list in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9427163/remove-duplicate-dict-in-list-in-python)
However, I cannot figure out what to do?
does anybody know how to solve the problem?

what I expect to get is:

```
[{'id': '1', 'dlin': '1'}, {'id': '2', 'dlin': '1'}, {'id': '3', 'dlin': '1'}, {'id': '6', 'dlin': '1'}]
[{'id': '4', 'dlin': '2'}, {'id': '5', 'dlin': '2'}]
```

Comment: Can you post your expected output? It is a bit hard to understand what you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible solution is storing the `dlin` as key in dictionary (and dictionaries cannot have multiple equal keys) rather than removing duplicates explicitly afterwards:

```
campus = [{'id': '1', 'dlin': '1'}, {'id': '2', 'dlin': '1'},{'id': '3', 'dlin': '1'},{'id': '4', 'dlin': '2'},{'id': '5', 'dlin': '2'},{'id': '6', 'dlin': '1'}, ]

schools = {}
for c in campus:
    schools.setdefault(c['dlin'], []).append(c)

for s in schools.values():
    print(s)
```

Prints:

```
[{'id': '1', 'dlin': '1'}, {'id': '2', 'dlin': '1'}, {'id': '3', 'dlin': '1'}, {'id': '6', 'dlin': '1'}]
[{'id': '4', 'dlin': '2'}, {'id': '5', 'dlin': '2'}]
```

Comment: That is what I want but I do not understand what you did. What setdefault does in here

Comment: @AminBa The setdefault() method returns the value of a key from dictionary (if the key is in dictionary). If the key doesn't exist, it inserts key with a value to the dictionary - in this case empty list `[]` https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault

Comment: That was great!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer of Andrej, I solved another part of the question I had and I wanted just to share it here:

My question:

I am now involved in another issue related to the previous one:

I have this list of dictionaries, each informaton of a campus. multiple campuses might belong to a school. I have to distinguish and cluster them based on the similarity of their names.

```
campus = [
{'id': '1', 'name': 'seneca - york'}, 
{'id': '2', 'name': 'seneca college - north gate campus'},
{'id': '3', 'name': 'humber college - toronto campus'},
{'id': '4', 'name': 'humber college'},
{'id': '5', 'name': 'humber collge - waterloo campus'},
{'id': '6', 'name': 'university of waterloo toronto campus'}, 
]
```

my expected result can be reached by this small and neat code:

```
schools = {}
for c in campus:
    schools.setdefault(c['name'][:4], []).append(c)
print(schools)
```